# Problem in SSIS version while running integration project on visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, ssis-2016, sql-server-2022

I have downloaded the SQL Server Integration Service and installed in Visual Studio 2022. When I create a project with one Excel file as the source and an OLE DB destination, it's working and rows are inserted into the database.

But when a derived column section is dragged between them for running simple `UPPER` string function, during the run of the package, it throws an error:

> Error: 2024-01-21 08:09:24.81
> Code: 0xC000F427
> Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
> Description: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition (64-bit) of Integration Services or   higher.
> End Error

While creating this project, it's working fine and all the excel data was inserted into the database table student.

[Initial project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJDj3.png)

I choose OLED DB provider for SQL Server:

[choosing the provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Eyiu.png)

[Selecting the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Sht.png)

[Mapping the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdAoy.png)

And it's working fine.

I tried to integrate SSIS project in Visual Studio 2019 but it still throwing the same error.

Comment: Which **edition** (Express, Web, Standard, Developer, Enterprise) is your target SQL Server ? It looks like you have a possible issue here - not with VS

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2022, why are you using SSIS2016?

Comment: @marc_s currently I am targeting Developer edition of SQL server. Will the enterprise edition solve this issue?

Comment: @ThomA I am using latest version of SSIS i.e.  1.3.2

Comment: You've tagged [[tag:ssis-2016]] though; I'm asking why you're using that when you have a 2022 instance. And that looks like the version of the Visual Studio Extension.